# error comma expected after operand , error comma, colon, decorator or end of line

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
SECTION .data
matriz: DD 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
x:      DD 16 DUP (?)
out:   DD 16 DUP (?)
fmt:  DD "%d", 10, 0

SECTION .text

        GLOBAL main
        extern printf

main:
        MOV ESI, 0
        copia:
          MOV EDX, matriz[ESI]
          MOV x[ESI], EDX
          ADD ESI, 4
          CMP ESI,64
          JNE copia

        MOV  [val], EDX
        ;fst dword [val]
        PUSH ESP
        CALL printval
        POP ESP

        z1:
                MOV EBP x[0]
                ADD EBP,x[3]
                ROL EBP, 7
                XOR x[1], EBP

        z2:
                MOV EBP, x[1] ;z1
                ADD EBP, x[0] ;a
                ROL EBP, 9
                XOR x[2], EBP

        z3:
                MOV EBP, x[2]
                ADD EBP, x[1]
                ROL EBP, 13
                XOR x[3], EBP
        z0:
                MOV EBP, X[3]
                ADD EBP, X[2]
                ROL EBP, 18
                XOR x[0],EBP

printval:

        SUB ESP, 8
        FSTP qword [ESP]
        PUSH fmt
        CALL printf
        ADD ESP, 32
        RET
```

Comment: `printval` looks like it will unbalance the stack; you push 8 + 4 bytes before `call printf`, so `add esp,32` is too much.  You need ESP pointing at the return address you pushed before `call printval`.  Also note that `push esp` / `pop esp` is not useful for actually saving/restoring.  `pop esp` has the same effect as `mov esp, [esp]`, so it can't help you if ESP isn't pointing where it's supposed to be.  The stack isn't magic, the stack *is* just where ESP points.  This should be fairly easy to see once you fix syntax errors so you can build an executable and single-step it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention for what source line you received the error message, but several things are wrong, so here's a list.

> ```
> MOV EDX, matriz[ESI]
> MOV x[ESI], EDX
> ```

NASM will not accept this kind of addressing mode.

> NASM, in the interests of simplicity, also does not support the hybrid syntaxes supported by MASM and its clones, such as `mov ax,table[bx]`, where a memory reference is denoted by one portion outside square brackets and another portion inside. The correct syntax for the above is `mov ax,[table+bx]`.  Likewise, `mov ax,es:[di]` is wrong and `mov ax,[es:di]` is right.

So write it like (same for many other instructions):

```
MOV EDX, [matriz + ESI]
MOV [x + ESI], EDX
```

---

NASM doesn't use the MASM-style `dup (?)`.
Place your uninitialized data in the `.bss` section and write:

```
SECTION .bss
x:   resd 16        ; reserves 16 dwords
out: resb 64        ; reserves 64 bytes (just as many)
```

If you do want to place it in the `.data` section then use:

```
x:   times 16 dd 0  ; 16 repeats of `dd 0`
out: times 64 db 0  ; 64 repeats of `db 0` (just as many)
```

---

Using the `DD` (**D**efine **D**oubleword) directive for your format string is wrong! What you need is `DB` (**D**efine **B**yte):

```
fmt: db "%d", 10, 0
```

---

Most of the code regarding the use of `esp` does not make much sense! And tagging your question for [emu8086](/questions/tagged/emu8086) is not useful since that emulator can't work with these 32-bit registers.

Comment: See https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5 - NASM 2.15 and later have some MASM syntax compatibility; `symbol[esi]` is supported as equivalent to `[symbol + esi]`.  And `dup` and `?` are supported for `db` and so on.  But yes, +1 for explaining the standard NASM syntax, which the OP needs to use if they don't want to upgrade NASM, and should probably at least know about anyway.